# how to implement strategy pattern in php with OOP?

Tags: php

My coworker ask me how to dynamically implement methods in a class. What I come up with was strategy pattern. At the first time, I made regular strategy pattern, and at the end I understood it's not good idea to make property call function. Because the child class is controller class whose methods needs to be called directly. 
So, I'm trying to implement Package's method to B class directly. But I'm stuck when calling __call function. The function tried to implement works in class B. However, when it's extended the function I saved in B class doesn't work.

```php
<?php

class A {
    public $once = 0;
}

class B extends A {

    public $methods = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        //load package
        $package = new Package;
        //get method names
        $methods = get_class_methods($package);
        //loop to assign methods to class B instance
        foreach($methods as $method)
        {
            $this->methods[$method] = $this->setFunc($package, $method);
        }
    }
    //I made this function because [$package, $method] was regarded as
    // array instead of function when it is assigned to other variable
    private function setFunc($package, $methodName)
    {
        return function() use($package, $methodName)
        {
            return call_user_func([$package, $methodName]);
        };    
    }
}

//package class
class Package {
    public function hello_world(){
        return  "hello world";
    }
}

class C extends B{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        //assigning functions to class C
        foreach($this->methods as $key => $val)
        {
            //I did it in child class because dynamically produced properties
            // weren't recognized
            $this->$key = $val;
        }
    }

    //dynamically assigned functions to dynamic properties must be called by
    //__call function
    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        //I made this condition because calling function loops infinitely.
        if($this->once >= 1)
        {
            return;
        } 
        $this->once++;

        //not working here. nothing shown
        return $this->$name();
    }
}

$c = new C;

echo $c->hello_world(); //I want to display hello world!
```

Comment: I worked through the head first design patterns book but did the code in php, here's the strategy pattern chapter code https://github.com/bbathel12/HeadFirstDesignPatterns/tree/master/DuckSimulator . The quack and flying behavior of each duck is implemented using the strategy pattern.

Comment: I red the book too!. However, what I want to do is to directly inject method dynamically into a class, which is a little bit different from the duck program example. The problem is that calling function in C class extending B class cannot recognize the methods declared in class B.

Comment: replace `return $this->$name();` with `call_user_func($this->$name,[]);`

Comment: also in php7 this works `return ($this->$name)();`

Answer (score 0):

replace `return $this->$name();` with `call_user_func($this->$name,[]);`
or in php7 this works `return ($this->$name)();`